# Youtube Data API searching for all videos on a channel returns double results

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-data-api

I'm writing a PHP script that retrive all videos of a channel using **Google APIs Client Library for PHP** and **youtube.search.list** with params:

```
part = snippet
maxResults = 50
channelId = ...
type = video
order = rating
pageToken = [nextPageToken]
```

Scrolling all the results of pagination I see that sometimes the search returns videos that were present in the previous pages.
I have tested thoroughly and the calls to the next pages are correct with the right nextPageToke.

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). If you're really sure about the results, you can try remove such duplicates.

Comment: I'm already removing duplicates. The problem is on the performances of the script.

Comment: Have you tried to use `uploads` playlist that you can get with [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) and then get videos with [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) ?